# how do i assign a unique object name to every editText being generated

Tags: android, runtime, android-edittext

I have this code where a linearLayout contains 3 editTexts. although i have defined an id of each editText in the XML but when i inflate this view a couple of times in runtime how do i get to know which editText is being edited.

Also how will i get the text entered in the editText

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener{


EditText date;
View row[]=new View[30];
int rowNo=0;
LinearLayout itemForm;
boolean done=false;
EditText item[]=new EditText[30];
EditText rate[]=new EditText[30];
EditText quant[]=new EditText[30];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    itemForm=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_form);


}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(arg1==false && done==false){

        row[rowNo]=LinearLayout.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, null);
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_form)).addView(row[rowNo]);
                done=true;
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do here, are you sure you need 90 EditTexts and 30 Views? You probably should be using a custom list adapter.

Comment: arg0 is the View that was clicked, you can get it's Id and other info.